# Why do these three conditions imply divergence in probability?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, convergence-divergence, martingales

This is a follow up to [A martingale converging in distribution but not a.s. or in probability](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2978806/a-martingale-converging-in-distribution-but-not-a-s-or-in-probability?noredirect=1&lq=1). Suppose we have a sequence of integer-valued RVs that satisfies

(1) $P(X_n=a~i.o.)=1$ for each $a=-1,0,1$

(2) $\sup_n|X_n(w)|<\infty$ a.s.

(3) For some $p\in(0,1/2)$, $P(X_n=1),P(X_n=-1)\to p$ and $P(X_n=0)\to 1-2p$.

How does one show this sequence of RVs doesn't converge in probability?

**My Attempts:** Clearly $X_n$ converges in distribution to RV $X$ with $P(X=1)=P(X=-1)=p,P(X=0)=1-2p$. Assume by contradiction that $X_n$ converges in probability, then it must be the case that $X_n\to X$ in probability. So there must be a subsequence $X_{n_k}\to X$ a.s.. But I couldn't find a way to go forward.

Comment: The condition (1) can be clarified, does it mean that for each $a\in \{-1, 0,1\}$ that $P[X_n=a \quad i.o.]=1$?

Comment: @Michael That's right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm suspicious of this claim. Here's an example. I fold together the values $1$ and $-1$ from your situation, but that simplification is unimportant.

**Example:** On an appropriate probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal F,P)$ let $U$ be uniformly distributed on $(0,1)$ and let $\xi_1,\xi_2,\ldots$ be a sequence of independent $\{0,1\}$-valued random variables, independent of $U$, such that $P(\xi_n =1)=1/n$. For fixed $p\in(0,1)$ define
$$
X_n =\cases{
1,&$0<U\le p, \xi_n=0$,\cr
0,&$0<U\le p, \xi_n=1$,\cr
0,&$p<U<1, \xi_n=0$,\cr
1,&$p<U<1,\xi_n=1$.\cr
}
$$
Then $P(X_n=1)=p\cdot(1-{1\over n})+(1-p){1\over n}$, so $\lim_n P(X_n=1)=p$. Likewise, $\lim_n P(X_n=0)=1-p$.

You have
$$
P(X_n=1 \hbox{  i.o.})=p\cdot P(\xi_n=0\hbox{  i.o.})+(1-p)\cdot P(\xi_n=1\hbox{  i.o.})=p+(1-p)=1,
$$
and similarly $P(X_n=0\hbox{ i.o.})=1$.

Finally, let $Y:=1_{\{U\le p\}}$. The $P(X_n\not= Y)\le 2P(\xi_n=1)=2/n\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$. Thus $X_n$ converges in probability to $Y$.