# When $\mathbb{P}(C\cup D) = 0$? (Martingale)

Tags: probability, measure-theory, random-variables, martingales, filtrations

> **Theorem**: Let $(X_n,\mathcal{F}_n)_{n\geq 0}$ be a martingale with $|X_n - X_{n-1}| \leq M<\infty$. Let
> $C := \{{\lim X_n \ \mbox{exists and} < \infty}\} $ and $D:=\{\limsup X_n = +\infty \mbox{and} \liminf X_n = -\infty\}$. Then $\mathbb{P}(C\cup D)=1$. (*Reference: Durrett, Probability: theory and examples*)

My question: Is it possible to get $\mathbb{P}(C\cup D)=0$, if I omit the condition $|X_n - X_{n-1}| \leq M<\infty$?

Comment: You may find the example here useful: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2965136/martingale-oscillating-between-three-values